# Spring Transactions with Executor

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-transactions, threadpoolexecutor

I have a method something like:

```
@Transactional

public void method1() {
    taskExecutor.execute() -> {

        // do work here

    }
}
```

The `@Transactional` annotation isn't honored due to new thread pool.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you want to check spring's @Async support. By using the annotation instead of a custom executor spring will take care of the transaction handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a Class with a method of your work(will do) and set the `@Transactional` annotation on this method.Then inject this Class and invoke its work method in new thread pool.

For example:

```java
public class WorkClass {
   
    @Transactional  
    public void work() {
   
        //do work here...
   
    }
}
```

```java
@autowired
private WorkClass workClass;

@Transactional
public void method1() {
    taskExecutor.execute() -> {

        workClass.work();

    }
}
```

And you can adjust policy by Spring Transaction Propagation.